# File not being copied when deployed to iPod device

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

I have an application with some images in it. Recently I added a new one in and it displays fine on the simulator.

When I create a distribution build and do an ad-hoc install it works fine, but for reasons unknown the image doesn't appear.

I have tried

- "touching" the directory it is in
- Re adding it
- Cleaning the solution around 234087290 times

But to no avail! Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The file is definitly inside the "Copy Bundle Resources" folder.

Comment: Does the image get copied to the app bundle? Does the UIImage report correct image size?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the image is being copied into your bundle. In the Groups & Files pane on the LHS of XCode expand Targets and then your app build target. Check that you file is included under the "Copy Bundle Resources" section.

Other than that, there's the tried and tested "Xcode Voodoo dance": Clean All Targets, delete build folder, restart Xcode

Comment: Sorry not entirely sure where "Copy Bundle Resources" is? I select my app name under the targets section and hit apple i, from there...uhm?

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately none of your things seem to have worked, thanks anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is added in Xcode as part of the project. I've seen the case where adding the file to the folder in Finder will make it available on the Simulator, but not on the device, because it was not added in Xcode.

Comment: It's inside the copy bundle resources folder, presumably this is what you mean?